# How to look at code of some Android class?

Tags: android

I'm developing some Android application, and I need to look at source code of some Android class. I have tried to use Android Source tool (installed as Eclipse extension), but I can't still use "Open Declaration" for Android class, therefore I need to use alternative ways  . Please, suggest me, can I open code for some class on-line or download sources? Thank you in advance.

Comment: this might help http://www.mkyong.com/android/attach-android-source-code-to-eclipse-ide/ and http://www.vogella.com/blog/2010/12/14/android-source-code/

Comment: or this http://blog.blundell-apps.com/add-source-code-links-to-android-apis/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the link, which provides the class code with respect to their versions :

http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/

Comment: Please, it's good. So, please, tell me how can I look at code of some xml resources too?

Comment: can you please elaborate? xml resources?

Comment: I downloaded code for CalendarView, and I'm trying to make MyCalendarView class. I copy and paste code, and this code has relations to R.styleable.CalendarView and some others.

Comment: here is one link which may be helpful : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#CalendarView